# How to use regex with glob library

Tags: python, regex, glob

I have a folder with a number of input files to use for a D3 visualization. But, I'm having trouble getting my regex code to work with glob. This allows a user to specify years(Note: all my input files have formatting YYYY_MM_#*produpdt*###):

```
from glob import glob

years = "[\'2016\']"
months = "[\'12\']"
loc = "produpdt_files/"
file_list = []
for year in years:
    file_list.extend(glob(loc+year+"*"))
print file_list
```

How should I code this to work with years and months? The following does not work:

```
from glob import glob

years = "[\'2016\']"
months = "[\'12\']"
loc = "produpdt_files/"
file_list = []
for year in years:
    for month in months:
        print(loc+year+"_12"+"*")
        file_list.extend(glob(loc+year+"_"+month+"*"))
print file_list
```

Comment: As a side note, `years` is a string. When you iterate over a string (`for year in years`) you will get one character at a time. I assume that you don't really mean to do that. The same comment applies to your loop over `months`.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense with what I am seeing.

Comment: What are those hashes in the file names, numbers?

Comment: Yes they are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you want to feed into glob is `os.path.join(loc, "2016_12_*")`

Comment: Is there a way to use the variables "year" and "month" in that expression? I just tried os.path.join(loc, year+"_12_*") and that failed.

Comment: `os.path.join(loc, year+"12*")` and `os.path.join(loc, "2016_12_*")` are not equivalent. `year+"12*"` evaluates (with `year=2016`) to `201612*`. Notice that this doesn't have the underscore between the year and the month. The pythonic way to create strings is using string formats, so `os.path.join(loc, "{year}_{month}_*".format(year=2016, month=12))` is what you want.

Comment: Thanks Terrence for the pythonic way to create strings! And I was having trouble getting underscores to show up in StackOverflow-I probably have to add an escape character.

Comment: Are you still having problems, then?

Comment: Nope, you guys solved it. I used the following code: file_list.extend(glob(os.path.join(loc, year+"_"+month+"_*")))

Answer (score 0):

`glob` doesn't take regular expressions, so you need to write your own globber. But that's easy to do with `os.listdir`. You can use groups in the regex to look for multiple dates like `r"(2012|2013|2014)_(10|11)_\dproduptd\d{4}"`. The example below formats regex's like that using lists of years and months.

```
import os
import re

def produpdt_glob(path, years=None, months=None):
    if years is None:
        years = r'\d' * 4
    if months is None:
        months = r'[01]\d'
    regex = r'({})_({})_\dprodupdt\d{4}'.format('|'.join(years), '|'.join(months))
    match = re.compile(regex).match
    for fn in os.listdir(path):
        if match(fn):
            fn = os.path.join(path, fn)
            if os.path.isfile(fn):
                yield fn
```